# Why is my sort algorithm changing the array values?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

This is a simple bubble sort algorithm, part of my larger program, intended to sort an array of doubles. I previously tried sorting the same values with merge sort but I got the same output. I really fail to notice what I am missing.Can someone please point it out to me
Thanks in advance!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

int const POINTS = 5;
double dataPoints[POINTS] = { 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 0.2, 0.8 };

void sort(double dataPoints[])
{
    int i, j, flag = 1;    
    int temp;             
    for (i = 1; (i <= POINTS) && flag; i++)
    {
        flag = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < (POINTS - 1); j++)
        {
            if (dataPoints[j + 1] > dataPoints[j])      
            {
                temp = dataPoints[j];             
                dataPoints[j] = dataPoints[j + 1];
                dataPoints[j + 1] = temp;
                flag = 1;              
            }
        }
    }

}

int main()
{

    sort(dataPoints);

    for (int i = 0; i < POINTS; i++)
    {
        cout << dataPoints[i] << " ";
    }

}
```

```
Output:

0.8 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Good opportunity to use debugger.

Comment: ... and a good opportunity to read and fix the compiler warnings. You should be getting a warning about doublt-to-int conversion which would have led you straight to the problem.

Comment: change `int temp` to `double temp`...

Comment: Also, avoid globals.  Pass POINTS as a parameter.

Comment: I'm soft on `POINTS`. It's a global, but it's also constant. It's hard to screw up a constant. If you want variation in the sorting algorithm you'd be better off passing around a `std::vector`.

Comment: Remove the mergesort tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You swap `double`, with temporary of type `int`.

Use instead:

```
double temp;
```

or better `auto`:

```
const auto temp = dataPoints[j];             
dataPoints[j] = dataPoints[j + 1];
dataPoints[j + 1] = temp;
```

or even better, use `std::swap`:

```
std::swap(dataPoints[j], dataPoints[j + 1]);
```

If allowed, you can even use:

```
std::sort(std::begin(dataPoints), std::end(dataPoints), std::greater<>{});
```

Comment: Holy! Thank you! That was such a dumb mistake and I was breaking my head over it for hours. I need sleep.

Answer (score 3):

change the data type of temp variable to double.